# Scatter-plot matrix with lowess smoother

Tags: python, scatter-plot

**What would the Python code be for a scatter-plot matrix with lowess smoothers similar to the following one?**
[image]

I'm not sure about the original source of the graph. I saw it on [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/64789/exploring-a-scatter-plot-matrix-for-many-variables) on CrossValidated. The ellipses define the covariance according to the original post. I'm not sure what the numbers mean.

Answer (score 9):

I adapted the pandas scatter_matrix function and got a decent result:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
frame = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 4), columns=['A','B','C','D'])
fig = scatter_matrix_lowess(frame, alpha=0.4, figsize=(12,12));
fig.suptitle('Scatterplot matrix with lowess smoother', fontsize=16);
```

[image: Scatterplot matrix with lowess smoother]

---

This is the code for `scatter_matrix_lowess`:

```
def scatter_matrix_lowess(frame, alpha=0.5, figsize=None, grid=False,
                   diagonal='hist', marker='.', density_kwds=None,
                   hist_kwds=None, range_padding=0.05, **kwds):
    """
    Draw a matrix of scatter plots with lowess smoother.
    This is an adapted version of the pandas scatter_matrix function.

    Parameters
    ----------
    frame : DataFrame
    alpha : float, optional
        amount of transparency applied
    figsize : (float,float), optional
        a tuple (width, height) in inches
    ax : Matplotlib axis object, optional
    grid : bool, optional
        setting this to True will show the grid
    diagonal : {'hist', 'kde'}
        pick between 'kde' and 'hist' for
        either Kernel Density Estimation or Histogram
        plot in the diagonal
    marker : str, optional
        Matplotlib marker type, default '.'    
    hist_kwds : other plotting keyword arguments
        To be passed to hist function
    density_kwds : other plotting keyword arguments
        To be passed to kernel density estimate plot
    range_padding : float, optional
        relative extension of axis range in x and y
        with respect to (x_max - x_min) or (y_max - y_min),
        default 0.05
    kwds : other plotting keyword arguments
        To be passed to scatter function

    Examples
    --------
    >>> df = DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 4), columns=['A','B','C','D'])
    >>> scatter_matrix_lowess(df, alpha=0.2)
    """

    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from matplotlib.artist import setp
    import pandas.core.common as com
    from pandas.compat import range, lrange, lmap, map, zip
    from statsmodels.nonparametric.smoothers_lowess import lowess

    df = frame._get_numeric_data()
    n = df.columns.size
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=n, ncols=n, figsize=figsize, squeeze=False)

    # no gaps between subplots
    fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0)

    mask = com.notnull(df)

    marker = _get_marker_compat(marker)

    hist_kwds = hist_kwds or {}
    density_kwds = density_kwds or {}

    # workaround because `c='b'` is hardcoded in matplotlibs scatter method
    kwds.setdefault('c', plt.rcParams['patch.facecolor'])

    boundaries_list = []
    for a in df.columns:
        values = df[a].values[mask[a].values]
        rmin_, rmax_ = np.min(values), np.max(values)
        rdelta_ext = (rmax_ - rmin_) * range_padding / 2.
        boundaries_list.append((rmin_ - rdelta_ext, rmax_+ rdelta_ext))

    for i, a in zip(lrange(n), df.columns):
        for j, b in zip(lrange(n), df.columns):
            ax = axes[i, j]

            if i == j:
                values = df[a].values[mask[a].values]

                # Deal with the diagonal by drawing a histogram there.
                if diagonal == 'hist':
                    ax.hist(values, **hist_kwds)

                elif diagonal in ('kde', 'density'):
                    from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde
                    y = values
                    gkde = gaussian_kde(y)
                    ind = np.linspace(y.min(), y.max(), 1000)
                    ax.plot(ind, gkde.evaluate(ind), **density_kwds)

                ax.set_xlim(boundaries_list[i])

            else:
                common = (mask[a] & mask[b]).values

                ax.scatter(df[b][common], df[a][common],
                           marker=marker, alpha=alpha, **kwds)
                # The following 2 lines are new and add the lowess smoothing
                ys = lowess(df[a][common], df[b][common])
                ax.plot(ys[:,0], ys[:,1], 'red', linewidth=1)

                ax.set_xlim(boundaries_list[j])
                ax.set_ylim(boundaries_list[i])

            ax.set_xlabel('')
            ax.set_ylabel('')

            _label_axis(ax, kind='x', label=b, position='bottom', rotate=True)

            _label_axis(ax, kind='y', label=a, position='left')

            if j!= 0:
                ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)
            if i != n-1:
                ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)

    for ax in axes.flat:
        setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), fontsize=8)
        setp(ax.get_yticklabels(), fontsize=8)
    return fig

def _label_axis(ax, kind='x', label='', position='top',
    ticks=True, rotate=False):

    from matplotlib.artist import setp
    if kind == 'x':
        ax.set_xlabel(label, visible=True)
        ax.xaxis.set_visible(True)
        ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position(position)
        ax.xaxis.set_label_position(position)
        if rotate:
            setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=90)
    elif kind == 'y':
        ax.yaxis.set_visible(True)
        ax.set_ylabel(label, visible=True)
        # ax.set_ylabel(a)
        ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position(position)
        ax.yaxis.set_label_position(position)
    return

def _get_marker_compat(marker):
    import matplotlib.lines as mlines
    import matplotlib as mpl
    if mpl.__version__ < '1.1.0' and marker == '.':
        return 'o'
    if marker not in mlines.lineMarkers:
        return 'o'
    return marker
```